# locate missingness in fitted model in R

Tags: r, na

Consider fitting a `coxph` model with, say, 100 data points. Only 95 are included in the analysis, while 5 are excluded due to being `NA` (i.e. missingness). I extract the residuals on the fitted data so I have a residual vector with 95 observations. I would like to include the residuals back into the original data frame, but I can't do this since the lengths are different.

How do I identify which observations from the original data frame were not included in the model, so I can exclude/delete them to make the two lengths the same?

(The original data is much larger so it's hard to locate where data are missing...)

Comment: Maybe `na.omit` but not sure exactly what you're after.  Usually you'd provide a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: i would know what to do to find rows w/ missing values for a specific column, but I don't know what coxph method classifies something as 'missingness' per say

Comment: Did you exclude the 5 values yourself, or was this some action taken by `coxph`? If the former, you know what the indices are of the values you excluded (or included), so map the observations onto that collection of indices.

Comment: it's the latter, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-fit your model, setting the `na.action` argument to `na.exclude`. This pads the residuals and fitted values that are part of the fitted object with `NA`s. If your original model is `zn50`:

```
zn50_na <- update(zn50, na.action=na.exclude)
```

This should give you `residuals(zn50_na)` and `fitted(zn50_na)` of the appropriate length. See `?na.omit` for more info.

Comment: tried that; missing values are as such though, so it's coxph that's calculating the missingness-> bmi=8165, smoke=12862, dod=299067